# Dynamically resize divs

Tags: html, menu, resize, sliding

I’ve done a lot of research and have not gone anywhere.

I am trying to find a way to dynamically re-size a div when a sliding menu is expanded from the left side of the screen.

Ideally the sliding menu will resize the div's width as the menu expands.

Any suggestions would be great?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to your solution:
http://jsbin.com/inayeg/2/edit

If you don't want to expand the menu on hover, but on click for example, you will have to use javascript.

For that, simply add a button with, eg id '#mybutton', then add this javascript:

```
var expandBt = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
expandBt.onclick(function() {
  menu.style.width = '15%'; // expand menu
});
// record a counter for clicking collapse/expand, or place another button to collapse.
```

Note: you can of course replace percentages with pixels. Just don't float the #main div, because otherwise it will adapt its width to min-width and not max-width.